# Using Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead plugin in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I was looking all day on how I can apply twitter bootstrap's typeahead plugin and can't find anything. Now, how can I use twitter bootstrap typeahead in codeigniter?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the source to be from some controller method?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the autocomplete records from the database. :)

Comment: Very good way of welcoming someone to the community, by closing his question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [BS Typeahead fork](https://gist.github.com/1866577), it supports ajax calls.

```
# This example does an AJAX lookup and is in CoffeeScript
  $('.typeahead').typeahead(
    # source can be a function
    source: (typeahead, query) ->
      # this function receives the typeahead object and the query string
      $.ajax(
        url: "/lookup/?q="+query
        # i'm binding the function here using CoffeeScript syntactic sugar,
        # you can use for example Underscore's bind function instead.
        success: (data) =>
          # data must be a list of either strings or objects
          # data = [{'name': 'Joe', }, {'name': 'Henry'}, ...]
          typeahead.process(data)
      )
    # if we return objects to typeahead.process we must specify the property
    # that typeahead uses to look up the display value
    property: "name"
  )
```

For example :-

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.get('/typeahead', { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data.options);
        });
    }
});
```

OR you can use :- [Ajax-Typeahead](https://github.com/pwarelis/Ajax-Typeahead) this plugin works well

Comment: Great answer, used it myself just yesterday

Comment: thank you @Vlakarados yeah,its a good plugin.

Comment: Hmmm. I think my question is wrong. I think it should "How to get records from database and use in typeahead in codeigniter."

Comment: @RyanJanBorja if you saw my link properly you will come to know `$("#ajax-typeahead").typeahead({
    ajax: "/path/to/source"
});` here you have to write url of a file where you are fetching your data from db

Comment: Just return a json_encoded `result` from your object - `echo json_encode(array('options' => $this->DBModel->GetAllSomething()->result()));`

Comment: if you got your answer then accept this answer so that any one who will face similar problem will come to know @RyanJanBorja

Comment: I posted another question and I found the answer there.